# Help with java calendar

Tags: java, swing

Need help to finish my java calendar.

Can anyone see why the text that is written on the date today are not saved?

And how can I ensure that written text is saved in OnDeleteEvent method when the window is closed?

My Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;

import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;

public class Diary extends JPanel
{
    private JCalendar calendar;
    private JTextArea text;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    private Value days = null;
    private String date = null;

    public Diary()
    {
        calendar = new JCalendar();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        text = new JTextArea(5,15);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                scroll.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        date = GetCalendarDate();
        days = Load();

        calendar.addPropertyChangeListener(new OnDaySelected());
        calendar.addPropertyChangeListener(new OnDeleteEvent());

        setLayout (new BorderLayout());
            add(calendar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static Value Load()
    {
        Value days;
        try
        {
            days = Value.loadFile("Diary.dat");
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            days = Value.makeTable();
        }
        return days;
    }

    private static void Save( Value days )
    {
            try
            {
                Value.saveFile(days,"Diary.dat");
            }
            catch( Exception e)
            {
                Value.makeTable();
            }

    }

    private String GetCalendarDate()
    {
        Date d = calendar.getDate();
        String dat = sdf.format(d);
                return dat;
    }

    private String GetDayText( String date )
    {
              try
              {
                  Value v = Value.makeString(date);
                  String texti = days.get(v).asString();
                  return texti;
              }
              catch( Exception e)
              {
                  return "";
              }
    }

    private void SetDayText( String date, String text )
    {
        Value v = Value.makeString(date);
                if(text == null)
                    days.put(v,null);
                else
                    days.put(v, Value.makeString(text));

    }

    public void SetDate( String newdate )
    {
        if( newdate==date ) return;
        if( date!=null && GetDayText( date )!= text.getText() )
        {
            SetDayText(date,text.getText());
            Save(days);
        }
        date = newdate;
        text.setText(GetDayText(date));
    }

    private class OnDaySelected implements java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
    {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
        {
            SetDate(GetCalendarDate());
        }
    }

    private class OnDeleteEvent implements java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
    {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
        {
            if(GetDayText(date) != text.getText())
            {
                SetDayText(date, text.getText());
                Save(days);
            }
            // how to close the program and ensure that unsaved text is saved
            // before the application closed? 


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Diary");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Diary());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Six questions; eleven answers; zero accepted; zero votes. Please see [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if( date!=null && GetDayText( date )!= text.getText() )`

You mean `if( newdate!=null && GetDayText( newdate)!= text.getText() )` don't you?

> And how can I ensure that written text is saved in OnDeleteEvent method when the window is closed?

Register a `WindowListener` on the window.

Edit:

Note, that this might not necessarily return true for equal texts:
`newdate==date` 

 This depends on `newdate` being exactly the same object as `date` (which is quite probable since strings are immutable and might come from the JVM's string pool). However, you'd better use `(newdate == null && date == null) || (newdate != null && newdate.equals(date))`, i.e. if both strings are null or they have the same content they're equal.

Comment: if( newdate==date ) return;                                         if( newdate!=null && GetDayText( newdate )!= text.getText() )              Does nothing. Text doesnt appear when i open the diary again but it show text for every other day.

Comment: Did you debug that code? Did you add log statements to see whether exceptions are thrown? For example, you have `catch(Exception e) { return ""; }` in `GetDayText()`, did you check that there's no exception there, returning ""?

Comment: ANother question: What is `Value` ? Could you post some code? Esp. `Value.put(Value, String)` looks somewhat strange.